Does Navier-Stokes equations get correct result for complex turbulent flow without turbulence model?
Does Navier equations (1822 formulation)  get correct result for complex turbulent flow without turbulence model?
Is this 1822 formulation?


Note that the header says, "Navier-Stokes EquationS" (plural).  You are missing an "equation of state" that relates $p$ to $\rho$.  For incompressible flow, this becomes $\Delta \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$.  The equations have been validated extensively in computer simulations and do an extremely good job when the flow being modeled satisfies the assumptions (Newtonian viscosity, equation of state is satisfied, stay away from scales on the order of the mean free path between molecules, etc.)  The problem is, for low viscosity flows,

you have to have very high spatial and time resolution in your simulation for accuracy, which means it taes a lot of computing power and gets prohibitively slow.

@pwf I edit my picture..

The short answer is: you either resolve or model.
Resolution forces finer grids (since coarse grids may make numerical methods "explode" or introduce unphysical extra numerical diffusion into the system, producing "bad results"); modeling requires some experience (someone would say cooking) and insight in the physics of turbulent flows.
Here a picture of qualitative distribution of turbulence length-scales in a flow: the larger ones (the ones with small wave number $\kappa$) are usually resolved, the smaller ones (the ones with large wave number $\kappa$) are usually modeled. Further discussion at the end of this answer.

Navier$-$Stokes equations
First of all, Navier$-$Stokes equations for constant and uniform density are the set of the incompressibility constraint (replacing the mass equation, and appearing as a algebraic constraint and not as a dynamical equation) and the momentum equation
$$\begin{cases}
 \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 \\
 \rho \partial_t \mathbf{u} + \rho (\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{u} - \mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} + \nabla p = \rho \mathbf{g} \ ,
\end{cases}$$
with the proper initial and boundary conditions, being $\mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u}$ the divergence of the viscous stress tensor for incompressible flows. This can be easily proved using Cartesian coordinates,
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbb{S} = \nabla \cdot \left[ 2 \mu \frac{1}{2} \left(\nabla \mathbf{u} + \nabla^T \mathbf{u} \right) + \lambda \underbrace{(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})}_{=0} \mathbb{I} \right] = \partial_i \left( \mu \partial_i u_k + \partial_k u_i \right) = \mu \left( \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} + \nabla \underbrace{\left( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} \right)}_{=0} \right) = \mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} \ .$$
This is the original formulation of the Navier$-$Stokes equations by Navier, (Cauchy, Fourier, de Saint Venant, et al.), and Stokes. As I've already told you in this question, where you can find direct references (or references in references) to the original papers and works by these scientists/engineers. It looks like that the viscous term $\mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u}$ appears in the momentum equation for the first time in the 1822 paper by Navier, who introduced it as a linear term (first order?) to take into account forces exchanged by neighboring regions of the flow by friction. Here a screenshot from page 414 of that memoir, where you can easily recognize the Cartesian components of the momentum equation

Simulation of turbulent flows
Now, let's focus on the simulation of turbulent flows.

Being Navier$-$Stokes the governing equations of the fluid system, if one is able/interested in accurately solving them, he gets the "correct result".

Need/desire for modeling comes from considerations on computational effort, both resources and time.

To accurately solve Navier$-$Stokes equations, you need to be able to resolve the smallest scales of the problem, whose characteristic dimension is usually a negative power of a Reynolds number, and thus become smaller and smaller as the Reynolds number increase. In order to solve these length-scales, you need a finer and finer mesh (in grid-based numerical methods), making the number of degrees of freedom of the discret(ized) equations and the computational resources larger and larger.

When you can't or you don't need to exactly solve NS equations (since the results you can get with alternative and cheaper approaches are good enough for you) you can use NS averaged equations, that exploit modelling of smaller scales to ease the computational cost. Some methods rely on the Reynolds-averaged NS equations, that for a constant density flow read for the averaged flow
$$\begin{cases}
 \nabla \cdot \overline{\mathbf{u}} = 0 \\
 \rho \partial_t \overline{\mathbf{u}} + \rho (\overline{\mathbf{u}} \cdot \nabla) \overline{\mathbf{u}} + \nabla \cdot (\overline{\mathbf{u}' \otimes \mathbf{u}'}) - \mu \nabla^2 \overline{\mathbf{u}} + \nabla \overline{p} = \rho \overline{\mathbf{g}} \ .
\end{cases}$$
These equations look like "exact" NS equations except for the presence of the term $\nabla \cdot (\overline{\mathbf{u}' \otimes \mathbf{u}'})$ that is the average of the product of fluctuations (and thus doesn't simplify with averaging), that can be meant as extra stresses acting on the average flow due to turbulent fluctuations. Many numerical methods for turbulent flows rely on different models of this term, that could produce "good results" (i.e. in agreement with experimental measurements).

Usually averaged equations are supplied with models for boundary conditions as well, if one is not interested in resolving boundary layers at walls.


Here a short list of key-words to google: turbulence spectrum, Kolmogorov scales, energy cascade (called so, even if it's not a mono-directional cascade)
Here an overview about a turbulence spectrum, with:

the inertial range at small wave-numbers, and thus large dimensions, and large energy content; these scales are usually case- and geometry-dependent and resolved
the viscous range at large wave-numbers, and thus small dimensions, and small energy content; these scales usually are (more) isotropic and geometry-independent and modeled



Why I always see formulation from my post(is this 1822?), what was change in formulation from 1822, 1845, 1895 etc?

I'd say nothing or minor changes (details relevant maybe only for science historians), but you can check the papers on your own.

Please, avoid asking many (and not so related questions) in the same post

it's up to you: you can read the .pdf of the original article by Navier I shared with you, or blindly trust Chatgpt. Just don't ask me why chatgpt is telling you something, because it's likely that not even Sam Altman can answer this question
